# No errors but still data not inserted to SQL Server table using ASP.NET with C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

This is my code

```
protected void btnnext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string clientId = Context.User.Identity.GetUserId();

    if (clientId != null)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=Mickey\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=db1;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFramework");
        SqlCommand com;

        con.Open();

        for(int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            string fn = GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Text;
            string ln = GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Text;
            string ad = GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Text;
            string pn = GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[6].Text;
            string em = GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[7].Text;

            string str = "insert into orders  
              (FirstName, LastName, Address, PhoneNumber, Email,
               TotalAmount,ModeofDelivery, ClientId, OrderNo, SpecialMess) 
               values(' " + fn + " ',' " + ln + " ',' " + ad+
               " ',' " + pn + " ',' " + em + " ',' " + Label6.Text + 
               " ',' " + Label4.Text + " ',' " + clientId + 
               " ',' " + Label1.Text + " ',' " + TextBox1.Text + " ' )"; 

            com = new SqlCommand(str, con);
            com.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        string stri = "insert into orderDetails(orderNo, clientId, productId, quantity) select ' " + Label1.Text + " ',client_id,product_id,amount from cart where client_id = ' " + clientId + " '  ";

        com = new SqlCommand(stri, con);
        com.ExecuteNonQuery();

        con.Close();

        Response.Redirect("~/Pages/orders.aspx");
    }
}
```

In this particular code, I am trying to insert data into two different tables.The first section of code is working properly where data is fetched from the gridview but the second section is not working properly even it is not throwing any errors still data does not get stored into the table.

```
   string stri = "insert into orderDetails(orderNo,clientId,productId,quantity) select ' " + Label1.Text + " ',client_id,product_id,amount from cart where client_id = ' " + clientId + " '  ";
        com = new SqlCommand(stri, con);
        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        Response.Redirect("~/Pages/orders.aspx");
```

Any solution?

Comment: Try running your insert statement directly in SSMS with your values, does it insert? Also, your code is open to injection. Use parameterized queries.

Comment: Then `where client_id = ' " + clientId + " '` is not satisfied so nothing is selected & nothing is inserted. (Note the *extra spaces* you have - another reason this must be rewritten as a parameterized query)

Comment: What type is client_id? You are comparing against it as it was a nvarchar with spaces on either side.

Comment: As Alex pointed out that client_id criteria does not meet. One thing I always do is put the break point right at com = new SqlCommand(stri, con). 
Then find out the content of stri in the watch. Execute that value in SSMS. Then you will find out why it does not insert

Comment: The problem is what Alex K mentioned.  Also, all your parameters have leading and trailing spaces.

Comment: Are you sure? I entered `'; DROP Table Orders; --` and get an error screen all the time now. DON'T use string concatenation. Use parameterized queries. They are a easier to write, faster and safer

Answer (score 3):

I would guess your subquery is not returning any rows because you're padding your id with spaces.

```
where client_id = ' " + clientId + " '  "
```

is going to produce sql that looks like

```
where client_id = ' 9 '
```

which probably wont match any records.

Comment: A problem he would not have if he would use paramaterized queries